# ASP.NET Ajax Dispose pattern equivalent in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax, memory-leaks

ASP.NET Ajax, has a dispose pattern by having a IDisposable interface which let you free up the resources.

1. How the freeing up of resources should be done in jQuery? Is there any similar pattern?
2. How / when the dispose function is invoked by the ASP.NET Ajax library?
3. Do we have to worry about memory leak if the page will be reloaded after a period of time?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How the freeing up of resources should be done in jQuery? Is there any similar pattern?

jQuery will handle detaching event handlers that were attached to DOM elements using **[`bind()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind)**. As as a result there should be far fewer dangling references to DOM elements than if the developer was responsible for detaching event handlers themselves. However it does this only when the page unloads (i.e. the `unload` event of the `window` object). At that time it iterates its event cache (`jQuery.cache`) and removes event listeners from elements, so that the browser can deduce that those elements are no longer referenced and reclaim the memory used by them.

There is no `IDisposable` pattern per-say in jQuery. For your own objects, you must manage the disposing yourself. `$(window).bind('unload', myCleanupFunction)` is a good start for this. There's nothing wrong with simply implementing a `dispose` method on your objects, and calling it from within this cleanup function.

In broad terms, any object property or global variable that can/may have a circular reference should be given particular attention and destroyed (**[`delete` or `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596782/how-to-unset-a-javascript-variable)** will suffice). Any references to DOM elements should be deleted or nulled. Any references to **[closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures)** that closed around DOM elements should be deleted or nulled (event handlers are a common source of this pattern). If you remove elements from the DOM, do so with **[`remove()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/remove)**, which will automatically clear jQuery-bound event handlers from your elements.

> How / when the dispose function is invoked by the ASP.NET Ajax library?

Like jQuery, the ASP.NET AJAX framework hooks into the `unload` event of the `window` object to perform some reference cleanup. Upon unload of the page `Sys.Application.dispose` is called and **[the following occurs](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/03/07/asp-net-ajax-in-depth-application-events.aspx)**:

1. If you have created a `pageUnload()` function in your application, that function is called
2. It calls `dispose()` on any object that have you have registered with the application.
3. It raises the Application `unload` event.
4. It disposes the `ScriptLoader` instance.

ASP.NET AJAX components, controls and behaviors are by default registered automatically with the `Sys.Application` object when the component is created (in the `Sys.Component` constructor). Anything that inherits from `IDisposable` is automatically **[registered with the framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397726(loband).aspx)** upon instantiation (and placed in `Sys.Application._disposableObjects`).

For objects that implement `IDisposable`, the `dispose()` method of your instance(s) is called (just like on the server). However you are still responsible for the actual free-ing of references (just like on the server).

IOW you *do* still need to take care to `delete` or `null` properties of your objects in the `dispose` method. Same rules as jQuery apply here: any object property or global variable that can/may have a circular reference should be given particular attention, references to DOM elements should be deleted or nulled, references to closures that closed around DOM elements should be deleted or nulled.

Unlike jQuery however, ASP.NET AJAX will not automatically remove listeners you have bound with `Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler` (aka `$addHandler`) when the page unloads<sup>1</sup>. You must take care to do this yourself. The framework does provide **[`Sys.UI.DomEvent.clearHandlers(element)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310959(loband).aspx)** (aka `$clearHandlers`) to do this easily however. You would call it in your `dispose()` implementation and pass in any elements you have attached event listeners to with the framework.

`IDisposable` in the client is meant more as a convenient place to put your "unload" code, and as a way for the code to self-document itself. I suspect most people are not creating and disposing many objects during the lifetime of their application, but rather creating them once on page load, and destroying them once on page *un*load.

> Do we have to worry about memory leak if the page will be reloaded after a period of time?

A lot of effort has gone into profiling memory in DOM trees that do not unload often. In general, you don't have to worry too much *if the page unloads often* (this includes users navigating to other pages in your application). If it is a long-lived application (eg 
gmail), you have to take great care wrt to memory leaks. With long-lived applications memory containment should not be viewed as a premature optimization, but a very distinct likelihood. Granted it's not going to be a performance bottleneck (in contrast to I/O say), but in today's applications the DOM is way too much of a beast to let the browser just handle it. However the management of this is very tricky to get right.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>This feature is coming to version 4.0 in the form of an `autoRemove` parameter to `Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler`</sub>

Comment: Wow. What a precise answer. Thank you so much. It cleared all my questions.