# Tabpanel in Extjs4 has memory leak?

Tags: extjs4, tabpanel

every one!
I use tablpanel in extjs4,found the memory in IE8 didn't reduce when remove the panel in tabpanel,and also raised when add the panel again.so I write a test as below:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
var currentItem;
var tabs = Ext.createWidget('tabpanel', {
    renderTo: 'tabs',
    resizeTabs: true,
    enableTabScroll: true,
    width: 600,
    height: 250,
    defaults: {
        autoScroll:true,
        bodyPadding: 10
    }
});

var __my_task = '';
var i = 0;
try{
    __my_task = {
            run: function(){
                if (i % 2 == 0){
                    for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                        addTab(true);
                    }
                }else{
                    var items = [];

                    tabs.items.each(function(item){
                        if(item.closable){
                            if(!false || item != this.item){
                                items.push(item);
                            }
                        }
                    }, this);

                    Ext.each(items, function(item){
                        tabs.remove(item);
                        item.destroy();
                    }, this);
                } // else
                i ++;
            },
            interval: 300
    }
    Ext.TaskManager.start(__my_task);
}catch(e){}

// tab generation code
var index = 0;
function addTab (closable) {
    ++index;
    tabs.add(Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel',{
        title: 'New Tab ' + index,
        iconCls: 'tabs',
        closable: !!closable
    }));
}
```

});

run it in IE8,the memory will raised so quickly,my code is wrong ? any question for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's hardly to evaluate if there is memory leak in Javascript (Extjs written in JS as you know). The object may be deleted with `delete()` (destroy() will use it) but cannot sure when the memory will be actually released.

You can find more about Javascript garbage collector in [Deleting or setting to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947995/when-should-i-use-delete-vs-setting-elements-to-null-in-javascript) and [Javascript garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection)