# Trying to delete a false property from an object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to delete the object properties that don't evaluate to true. What am I doing wrong?

```
var object = {
  obj1: NaN,
  obj2: false,
  obj3: "Don't delete",
  obj4: "Please don't delete"

};

var onlyTruthy = function(object) {
  for (var key in object) {
    if (object[key] === false) {
      delete object[key];
    }
  }
  return(object)
};
```

Comment: should properties with `NaN` deleted?

Comment: You're using `=== false` that will only check for falsey `boolean`, not for anything that is *evaulated* to be falsey. Try `!object[key]` instead. Also, you better use `Object.keys` instead.

Comment: What is your expected result from that function when you pass in the variable named `object`? Please add that info to the question.

Comment: None of your example object's properties "evaluate to true". But two of them are "truthy".

Answer (score 5):

For deleting all [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) properties, you could use just a check of the value.

```
if (!object[key]) {
    delete object[key];
}
```

With your check `object[key] === false`, you perform a strict comparison with `false`. This means, the value is checked against the type (Boolean) and the same value. But you need - kind of - less. Just a check for a not truthy value.

Please keep in mind, that properties with value `0` are deleted too.

Working code:

```js
var object = { obj1: NaN, obj2: false, obj3: "Don't delete", obj4: "Please don't delete" },
    onlyTruthy = function (object) {
        for (var key in object) {
            if (!object[key]) {
                delete object[key];
            }
        }
        return object;
    };

onlyTruthy(object);
console.log(object);
```

Comment: adding to that, triple equals is strict equality. So since NaN is not false, NaN === false, will be false

Answer (score 0):

Just use if(!object[key]) for truth values without comparison with exact falsy values.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to delete the object properties that don't evaluate to true. What am I doing wrong?

The problem is that you're using [the "identity" or "strict equality" operator: `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity) instead of [the normal "equality" operator: `==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality). You aren't allowing the program to do any sort of finagling when you ask it "are these two things the same?".

Here's some examples:

```
 1   ==  1        // true
"1"  ==  1        // true
 1   == '1'       // true
 0   == false     // true
 0   == null      // false

 0   == undefined // false
null == undefined // true
```

vs:

```
3 === 3   // true
3 === '3' // false!
```

When you write `... === false`, the only time that will "*evaluate to true*" is when the variable is actually equal to `false`. It won't "*evaluate to true*" if the variable was `null` or `undefined`.

See this question for even more detail on the problem:

[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Just changing the `===` operator to `==` isn't going to solve things, either. You're going to have to more closely match the problem definition, and check if things *don't* evaluate to *true*.

This "*evaluates to true*" concept is so common in JS that they built it straight into their flow control statements, like [`if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) and [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while):

```
if (... something that evaluates to true ...) {
   // ... do something
}

while (... something that evaluates to true ...) {
   // ... do something
}
```

If you combine this with [the logical not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT), then you can use this same "evaluates to true" check to find things that *don't* evaluate to true:

```
if (!object[key]) {
  delete object[key];
}
```

This is the "right" way to do things in Javascript (or at least [the most "canonical"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34920/what-does-canonical-mean)).

Comment: The first half of your answer is incorrect, because `== false` doesn't work for the OP's data either (it won't work for falsy values `NaN`, `null`, and `undefined`).

Comment: @nnnnnn: I see the problem with what you are pointing out. I imply that "fixing the equality operator" would work, though I don't state explicitly that checking for false isn't the same thing as checking that it evaluates to true, and that they'd need to further correct the expression. I think this is because I was intending to point out the `===` part with the first section. I did some tweaks that slightly improve this, though I admit I should unravel the first "solution" suggestion a bit further.

Answer (score 0):

Due to discussions over [delete performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947995/when-should-i-use-delete-vs-setting-elements-to-null-in-javascript), if just want to filter unwanted properties and don't mind to use a new variable this would be a good answer:

```js
var object = { obj1: NaN, obj2: false, obj3: "Don't delete", obj4: "Please don't delete" },
    result = {};
Object.keys(object).forEach(k => object[k] && (result[k] = object[k]));

console.log(result);
```