# delete property vs creating new object

Tags: javascript, performance

So I have an object as follows:

```
var data = [
    {
        unmatchedLines: [], //possible big array ~700+ lines per entry
        statusCode: 200,
        title: "title",
        message: "some message",
        details: [],
        objectDetails: []
    },
    {
        //same object here
    }
];
```

This array gets filled by service calls and then looped through for merging the output before sending this result back to the frontend.

```
function convertResultToOneCsvOutput(data) {
    var outPutObject = {
        unmatchedLines: [],
        responses: []
    };
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i].fileData) {
           outPutObject.unmatchedLines = outPutObject.unmatchedLines.concat(data[i].fileData);
        }

        outPutObject.responses.push({
            statusCode: data[i].statusCode,
            title: data[i].title,
            message: data[i].message,
            details: data[i].details,
            objectDetails: data[i].objectDetails,
        })
    }

    return outPutObject;
};
```

Now I was first using `delete` to get rid of the `unmatchedLines` from the `data` object so that, in stead of creating a whole new object and pushing this to the output I could do:

```
 delete data[i].unmatchedLines;
 outPutObject.responses.push(data[i]);
```

But then I read that `delete` is very slow and stumbled upon a post stating that putting this to `undefined` in stead of using `delete` would be faster.

My question:

What is better to use in the end? `delete`, setting to `undefined` or creating a new object in itself like I am doing right now?

Comment: You could read this: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/#de-referencing-misconceptions

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Nice, thank you for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither is "better."

It is true that when you `delete` a property from an object, on many modern engines that puts the object into a slower "dictionary mode" than it would be if you didn't delete the property from it, meaning that subsequent property lookups on that object (`data[i]` in your case) will be slower than they were before the `delete`. So setting the property to `undefined` instead (which is not quite the same thing) may be appropriate in those **very rare** situations where the speed of property access on the object matters.

Comment: Just out of interest is this `dictionary` mode only temporary until the GC runs or is it a permanent thing for the lifetime of the object?

Comment: isn't `null` better than `undefined`?

Comment: What about creating the new object and pushing that? Is that going to be the same thing and setting the `undefined`?

Comment: @ste2425: Lifetime of the object. Modern JavaScript engines turn objects into instances of runtime-generated classes, producing subclasses when you add properties; *removing* properties is unusual and changes the nature of the object.

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş: No. You can use an value you want, but `null` isn't better than `undefined`. `undefined` has a slight advantage over `null` in that the result of reading the property is the same (`undefined`) as when you don't have the property at all, but again, you can use any value you want.

Comment: @Tikkes: It won't be the same thing, but it will avoid the issue with `delete` slowing property access on the object down.

Answer (score 2):

It could be true, but it really depends on the length of the list, however:

> any performance difference between the two techniques is going to be
>   immeasurably small in any typical case.

( [more info about delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947995/when-should-i-use-delete-vs-setting-elements-to-null-in-javascript) )

Anyway: if you really need extra performance, you should consider dealing with clones and an immutable data-set ( [more info about immutable performances](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/304574/does-immutability-hurt-performance-in-javascript) )

Comment: This is extra info and is useful in turn, I really would like to know why the downvote was placed...