# Deleting and making it null difference in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var s= {type: "beetle", price : "xxx", popular: "yes" ,.... };
```

If I have to remove  all the properties of `s` how should I do it?

- Should it be `delete s.type; delete s.price; delete s.popular` .. so on.
- Or `s = null;`?
- Or would `s` going out of scope delete the properties?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use delete vs setting elements to null in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947995/when-should-i-use-delete-vs-setting-elements-to-null-in-javascript)

Comment: `delete s` doesn't do anything - the `delete` operator is used to delete a _property_ of an object, not the object itself.  See [help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Comment: no. but instead you can just do `s = undefined;` this way you its good as deleting the variable.

Comment: Yes I mean delete s.car; forgot to put it as s.car. Thanks

Comment: @JohnMichaelVillegas Yes makingit undefined is correct. But How is s= null  different from delete s.car ? we are removing s's reference to car.

Comment: delete is for the property. so if you do `delete s.car` it will return a empty object since `car` is the only property of `s` variable. but `s = null` is setting the variable `s` to value which is `null`. if you have another property in `s` variable but in a child property of `car` if you execute `delete s.car` the proter `car` will be gone and the remaining property will remain.

Comment: final note: `delete s.car` is not same as `s = null`
`delete s.car;`
console.log(s) // print {}
`s = null;`
console.log(s) //print null

Comment: Not same for s but both handles property car in the same way or different ways?

Comment: @JohnMichaelVillegas PLease look into my question now as I have stated it clearly. Thanks.

Comment: I'm still waiting for the perfect solution. Thanks !

Comment: don't set it as `null` since null is still a value. doing `s = undefined`  will delete the variable `s`. if you `delete s.<property>`  the value of `s` will become `{}`

Comment: in a nutshell 
1. `delete` will remove the property of a object. if all property will remove the remaining value will be `{}`
2. `s = null` will *SET* a new value of the variable `s` to `null`
3. `s = undefined` will *SET* the variable in to `undefined` state.

Comment: bottom line `delete`, `s = null, `s = undefined` are all **NOT THE SAME**

Answer (score 0):

In MDN it said, "The JavaScript delete operator removes a property from an object; if no more references to the same property are held, it is eventually released automatically."

So that totally different one is set an object to be a null object and another won't work because s is not and property of any object.

Comment: Sorry i didnt put it correctly the first time. please look into it now as I made my question clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @vishnuprasad.v using s = null make s a null object, using delete s.car make s a empty object.

Comment: What happens to the property car in both these cases? Thats the question i have.

Answer (score 0):

When you set a property equals to null, it still exists but hasn't any value but if you delete it, it will no longer exist.

Comment: As  mentioned above the property is not made as null the variable that is having the property is made null. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They're not the same at all. Deleting the `car` property of `s` still leaves it as an object - admittedly it is an "empty" object with no properties of its own, but that is a very different value from `null`. For one thing, `{}` is still an object, and delegates to `Object.prototype`, so can access methods like `s.toString()` (which is used internally for coercion to a string value) and `s.hasOwnProperty(propname)` - `null` is just a primitive value which you can't call any methods on at all. For another, `{}` becomes `true` if coerced to Boolean (eg if you do `if (s)`), while `null` coerces to false.

So the values actually behave very differently.

Comment: Agreed but my concern is not about the s, the main thing is the deletion. Is the property deleted in both ways?.

Comment: @vishnuprasad.v I'm not entirely sure I understand the question. In both cases the property is deleted, in the sense that `s.car` will no longer work. But note that if `s` is `null`, then `s.car` raises a `TypeError`, while if `s` is `{}` (as it is after `delete s.car`), `s.car` raises no error and returns `undefined`. Some additional context behind the question would help to give a useful answer.

Comment: Thanks Robin ! I have updated the question please let me know if you find the question convincing. Thanks

Comment: Zignmond - Thanks actually you have given me the answer - s.car is deleted in both the cases so instead of deleting all the properties one by one i can just use s = null  to remove them. THis  is just for the deletion of properties which i dont need anymore.