# How to delete a variable?

Tags: javascript

Here is my javascript code, I want to delete the variable code so that it has value undefined.

```js
var code = $(this).data('code');
var userelm = $(this);
```

Here I'm doing the check:

```js
if($('.code-1').val()!='' && $('.code-2').val()!='' && $('.code-3').val()!=''){
    if(code==$('.code-1').val()+$('.code-2').val()+$('.code-3').val()){
        $('.overlay').remove();
        $('.code-box').remove();
        $('.close-lock').remove();
        userelm.ajaxloader(); //own function
        userelm.off();
        delete code;
        console.log(code);
        delete userelm;
    }
}
```

Why does this program not remove the `code` variable so it has the value undefined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to unset a Javascript variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596782/how-to-unset-a-javascript-variable)

Answer (score 28):

### Delete a variable in JavaScript:

**Summary:**

The reason you are having trouble deleting your variable in JavaScript is because JavaScript won't let you.  You can't delete anything created by the `var` command unless we pull a rabbit out our bag of tricks.

The delete command is only for object's properties which were not created with var.

**JavaScript will let you delete a variable created with var under the following conditions:**

1. You are using a javascript interpreter or commandline.
2. You are using eval and you create and delete your var inside there.

**Demo on terminal, Use the `delete boo` or `delete(boo)` command.**  A demo with `js` command line terminal let you delete a variable.

```
el@defiant ~ $ js

js> typeof boo
"undefined"

js> boo
typein:2: ReferenceError: boo is not defined

js> boo=5
5

js> typeof boo
"number"

js> delete(boo)
true

js> typeof boo
"undefined"

js> boo
typein:7: ReferenceError: boo is not defined
```

**If you MUST set your variable to undefined in JavaScript, you have one option:**

Demo in javascript page: put this in `myjs.html`:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        document.write("aliens: " + aliens + "<br>");
        document.write("typeof aliens: " + (typeof aliens) + "<br>");
        var aliens = "scramble the nimitz";
        document.write("found some aliens: " + (typeof aliens) + "<br>");
        document.write("not sayings its aliens but... " + aliens + "<br>");
        aliens = undefined;
        document.write("aliens set to undefined<br>");
        document.write("typeof aliens: " + (typeof aliens) + "<br>");
        document.write("you sure they are gone? " + aliens);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Open myjs.html with a browser, it prints this:

```
aliens: undefined
typeof aliens: undefined
found some aliens: string
not sayings its aliens but... scramble the nimitz
aliens set to undefined
typeof aliens: undefined
you sure they are gone? undefined
```

**Warning** When you set your variable to `undefined` you are assigning a variable to another variable.  If someone poisons the well by running `undefined = 'gotcha!'`, then whenever you set your variable to undefined, it becomes: "gotcha!".

### How should we check if a variable has no value?

Use null instead of undefined like this:

```
document.write("skittles: " + skittles + "<br>");
document.write("typeof skittles: " + (typeof skittles) + "<br>");
var skittles = 5;
document.write("skittles: " + skittles + "<br>");
document.write("typeof skittles:" + typeof skittles + "<br>");
skittles = null;
document.write("skittles: " + skittles + "<br>");
document.write("typeof skittles: " + typeof skittles);
```

Which prints:

```
skittles: undefined
typeof skittles: undefined
skittles: 5
typeof skittles:number
skittles: null
typeof skittles: object
```

**If you are not using strict, you can delete variables created like this:**

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
   //use strict
   a = 5;
   document.writeln(typeof a);        //prints number
   delete a;
   document.writeln(typeof a);        //prints undefined
</script>
```

but if you uncomment `use strict`, the javascript will not run.

Comment: Isn't null subject to the same issue as undefined?  eg: null = 'gotcha';

Answer (score 24):

[Delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) does not delete a variable.

> The delete operator removes a property from an object.

You can try:

```
code = null;
```

Comment: If you use this variable you get null. If you use a non-existing variable you get a ReferenceError.

Answer (score 9):

The following works in strict mode also:

```js
"use strict";

var foo = 1;
console.log(foo);
// 1

foo = (function(){}());
console.log(foo);
// undefined
```

;)

Answer (score 8):

Try this in global scope:

```
x = 2;
delete window.x;
```

Answer (score 5):

delete doesn't affect variable names

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

```
x = 42;         // creates the property x on the global object
var y = 43;     // declares a new variable, y
myobj = {
  h: 4,
  k: 5
};

delete x;       // returns true  (x is a property of the global object and can be deleted)
delete y;       // returns false (delete doesn't affect variable names)
delete Math.PI; // returns false (delete doesn't affect certain predefined properties)
delete myobj.h; // returns true  (user-defined properties can be deleted)

delete myobj;   // returns true  (myobj is a property of the global object, not a variable, so it can be deleted)
```

Comment: Even if you reset a variable that was created with var (by setting it to null), you still have the variable name in memory don't you?

Answer (score 2):

**The others answer is quite simple and effective**

```
code = null;
code = undefined;
```

**But I want to share it's reason also, Why *delete code;* won't work**

delete is meant to delete properties of objects only. It's never meant (developed) to delete variables.

```
var obj = {
  'first' : 10;
}
//Following will print
console.log(obj.first)

delete obj.first;

//Following will print undefined/null/might give error
console.log(obj.first)
```

**Bounus (for developers)**

```
var item = 10;
delete item;
//Following will print 
console.log(item);

//The reason for upper is when we declare variable with var it is of 
//primitive data type and delete won't work.


item = 10;
delete item;
//Following will give reference error
console.log(item);

//The reason for upper is when we declare variable without var it is a 
//property of global 'window' object so delete work.
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables created on the fly will be [automatically deleted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) after there is no more reference to it.

```
(function(){
  var a = 1;
})(); //a available until here
```

Answer (score 0):

because you write **var** for define the variable.
if you use var can not delete it.
you must be write this

```
userelm = null;
```

or don't write **var**.
See this question: [How to unset or remove a Javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596782/how-to-unset-a-javascript-variable)

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to remove var , if you declared it in a function - when function ends, the inner var stops existing. You just don't have to declare variables globally.

Answer (score 0):

I was not successful with `myvariable = null`.

But I was successful with `myvariable = function(){};`