# Remove an array-Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I have an array like this:

```
var animals=["cat","dog","snake","rhino"];
```

But sometimes I have to delete this array(remove it from the dom).
I have tried animals.remove; and $(animals).remove() and animals.remove() but none of them did the trick.Any ideas?

Comment: Set animals.length = 0;

Comment: what do you mean by delete?

Comment: var animals=["cat","dog","snake","rhino"];
animals = [];
or
animals.length = 0

Comment: doing that will just clear the array.What i want is to make that array inaccessible(return undefined)

Comment: You want to delete *one specific position* of this array or make something like a *free(animals)* as we do in C ?

Comment: remove the array from the dom

Comment: if you want to clear your array see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/empty-an-array-in-javascript . If you want to delete it, see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963066/javascript-how-to-delete-a-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var animals=["cat","dog","snake","rhino"];
```

then to clear it do:

```
animals=[];
```

or

```
animals.length=0;
```

or

```
while(animals.length > 0) {
   animals.pop();
}
```

Comment: Why would someone need a loop to clear an array..?

Comment: @TJ please see this:http://jsperf.com/empty-javascript-array looping one is faster than animals=[];

Comment: That's interesting...

Answer (score 2):

Just Clear The Array

Using This 2 Methods

1. `animals.length =0`
2. `animals=[];`

Answer (score 2):

Just assign the `animals` array to a value `undefined` and the array data will be dereferenced and garbage collected.

Donot try to call `delete` operator that is explicit removal.

`animals = undefined`
OR

`animals = void 0`

Thanks

Comment: @AmitJoki You haven't came across [`<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>`..?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/134845/2333214) ;)

Comment: @TJ ah I have but not in this for :)