# delete operator does not actually delete the variable

Tags: javascript

May I know why it prompts 1 rather than undefined for the following javascript code?

```
function a(){
    var y=1;
    delete y;
    alert(y);
}

a();
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for delete? It operates on a property of an object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: Of course it doesn't. `delete` is for deleting properties: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963066/how-to-delete-a-variable

Answer (score 2):

[`delete` operates on the property of an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete); not on a non-object.

So, this would work:

```
var y = { val: 1};
delete y.val;
console.dir(y);
```

outputs:

```
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the MDN reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

> delete is only effective on an object's properties. It has no effect on variable or function names.