# Why does Firebug allow global variables declared in its console to be deleted?

Tags: javascript

I read in a book(JavaScript - the definitive Guide 6th Edition) that a global variable declared using `var` keyword cannot be delete using `delete` keyword. But I am able to do it running it in Firebug Console.

```
var a = 1;
delete a;// should return false but returns true in firebug.
```

I am not able to figure it out, why this is happening?

***Edit***

My question is not about how to unset a global variable, it is about if you declare a global variable as I did using `var` keyword, it creates a nonconfigurable property of the global object which cannot be deleted using `delete` keyword. But I am able to do it in Firebug Console, which should not happen.

Comment: You realise you have two different variables there? `trueval` is not the same as `truevar`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to unset a Javascript variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596782/how-to-unset-a-javascript-variable)

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed and those who voted to close: This is not a duplicate of that other question. This question asks why *Firebug* behaves this way. The other question and its answers don't discuss Firebug at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @NagaJolokia points out, `delete` is behaving differently in the Firebug console because the console is using `eval()` to execute the code.

You can see the same effect in action if you test a `delete` both in normal code and under `eval()`. Save this page and load it in any browser with the developer console open:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Eval/Delete Test</title>
    <script>
        console.log( 'Normal code, a = 1' );
        var a = 1;
        console.log( 'a is', typeof a, a );
        console.log( 'window.a is', typeof window.a, window.a );
        console.log( 'delete a OK?', delete a );
        console.log( 'delete window.a OK?', delete window.a );
        console.log( 'a is now', typeof a, window.a );
        console.log( 'window.a is now', typeof window.a, window.a );
        console.log( ' ' );
        console.log( 'Eval code, b = 1' );
        eval( 'var b = 1;' );
        console.log( 'delete b OK?', delete b );
        console.log( 'b is now', typeof b, window.b );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The code will log:

```
Normal code, a = 1
a is number 1
window.a is number 1
delete a OK? false
delete window.a OK? false
a is now number 1
window.a is now number 1

Eval code, b = 1
delete b OK? true
b is now undefined undefined
```

I also made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/EWYQQ/6/) with the same code ready to run. It produces the same output as above. The fiddle includes [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite), so you don't need to open the developer console.

For a more thorough explanation, see [NagaJolokia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17492452/1202830) and the [Firebug confusion section of this article](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#firebug_confusion).

Answer (score 2):

[Here is detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596782/how-to-unset-a-javascript-variable)

It will work, but technically it ought to be

```
delete window.some_var;
```

delete is supposed to be a no-op when the target isn't an object property. e.g.,

```
(function() {
   var foo = 123;
   delete foo; // wont do anything, foo is still 123
   var bar = { foo: 123 };
   delete bar.foo; // foo is gone
}());
```

But since global variables are actually members of the window object, it works.

When prototype chains are involved, using delete gets more complex because it only removes the property from the target object, and not the prototype. e.g.,

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype = { bar: 123 };
var foo = new Foo();
// foo.bar is 123
foo.bar = 456;
// foo.bar is now 456
delete foo.bar;
// foo.bar is 123 again.
```

So be careful.

EDIT: My answer is [somewhat inaccurate](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/) (see "Misconceptions" at the end). The link explains all the gory details, but the summary is that there can be big differences between browsers and depending on the object you are deleting from. `delete object.someProp` should generally be safe as long as `object !== window`. I still wouldn't use it to delete variables declared with `var` although you can under the right circumstances.

Comment: This copy-and-pasted explanation isn't correct. However the linked article http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/ is excellent and explains what is happening clearly.

Comment: This answer doesn't really relate to the OP's question: why does *Firebug* behave this way? @NagaJolokia gave the correct answer: it's because Firebug is using eval to execute the code. See the ["Firebug confusion"](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#firebug_confusion) section of the linked article (not the "Misconceptions" section) for an explanation of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Code in the Firebug console is executed with `eval`. And variable bindings created in eval code are mutable (this depends on the variable not already having been declared) and can be deleted.

See the [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5), section 10.5 item 2:

> If *code* is eval code, then let *configurableBindings* be **true** else let *configurableBindings* be **false**.

and item 8.c.i.:

> Call *env*’s CreateMutableBinding concrete method passing *dn* and *configurableBindings* as the arguments.

along with Table 17 in section 10.2.1:

> CreateMutableBinding(N, D)
>   Create a new mutable binding in an environment record. The String value *N* is the text of the bound name. If the optional Boolean argument *D* is **true** the binding is may be subsequently deleted.

Comment: Downvoter, please read the spec. and comment on why you downvoted, thanks!

Comment: +1 and agreed, you have the correct answer. To help readers, I took the liberty of copying in the cited paragraphs from the ECMAScript standard and added the relevant entry from Table 17.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Thanks for the improvement!

Answer (score 0):

Check your spelling

```
truevar != trueval
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be you did spelling mistake

```
var trueval = 1;
delete truevar;//spelling mistake here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete the global variable but you do like this

```
function Foo() {}

Foo.prototype = { bar: 123 };

var foo = new Foo();

// foo.bar is 123

foo.bar = 456;

// foo.bar is now 456

delete foo.bar;
// foo.bar is 123 again.
```

For more reference 
[How to unset a JavaScript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596782/how-to-unset-a-javascript-variable)

http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Comment: The OP is about global variables, not properties of other objects.