# unbinding a function after called once in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a function in jquery called navigation which is called once the page is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   navigation();
 });
```

the function definition is global. This function is again called on an ajax success function

```
var onSuccess=function(data){
    //unbind the previous navigation
   navigation();
  }
```

How do i unbind the previous navigation function so that the call on onSuccess is a new call

Comment: You can't "unbind" a function call, the real question is what `navigation()` does that needs to be unbound.

Comment: on clicking forward button or backward button it takes uto next page or previous page

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, loading another page (not just exchanging page content) would void any defined functions anyway?

Comment: i am exchanging the content....

Answer (score 0):

For what you're asking [deleting a global property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596782/how-to-unset-a-javascript-variable) and specifically the link given there: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/ will help you understand why what you want is not possible (or really akward, you need to read the linked text for the full story).

That makes me agree with @FabrícioMatté - you really, really want to rework your `navigation` function to keep track of what it loaded so you can just call it again and have it work out where to go next. There's no reason I can think of to redefine the function.