# clear all variable and functions defined by user in V8 javascript engine console

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

I am compiling a custom V8 javascript engine. What i want to do is delete only the functions and variables defined by users at runtime and not the functions defined in native code ie c++. currently i am making to shell.cc file given in samples of the v8 engine.
If not possible is there a way to redefine all native functions again after a script finishes its execution in c++
any help is appreciated

Comment: see if this can provide any insight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596782/how-to-unset-a-javascript-variable

Comment: I'd suggest to create a new v8::Context after a user script execution