# How to unset a Javascript Constant in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1596782/2034794) post, using `delete` keyword, we can delete JavaScript variable. But when I tried the same operations with constant but it is returning false when I try to delete constant. Is there any way to delete constants from memory?
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27019954/2034794) answer but its also not working.

Comment: what do mean you have tried this answer? that is - what exactly have you tried?

Comment: Constants are constants. If you read you're own links you will see that constants are not variables, ergo you can't redefine/delete constants

Comment: @AdrianPreuss, Is there any way to freeup memory used by constants?

Comment: You cannot create constants in JavaScript, unless you have created a frozen object.

Comment: @RoumelisGeorge, I am asking about ES6, Please check this MDN documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: Ok. As far as delete is concerned, delete is used to remove object attributes. That's is why it can only be used to remove global variables, that are considered part of the global object. Ex. you can do delete myObj.myVar, but you cannot do var myVar = 1; delete myVar.

Comment: @RoumelisGeorge, Thanks for updating my knowledge. But I cant set that constant as undefined also.

Comment: If you've properly read [the answer to the post you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25919959/1048572), you know that you **cannot delete variables** in JavaScript, you only can delete properties of the global object. And `const` declares standard, undeletable *variables*.

Comment: For those wondering how to do this because you are just testing something in a browser console, a workaround is to refresh the browser.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can't directly do it, looking at the specs show us that the value can be set, but not over-written (such is the [standard definition of a constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming))), however there are a couple of somewhat hacky ways of unsetting constant values.

**Using scope**

`const` is [scoped](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/05/es6-and-block-scope.html). By defining the constant in a block it will only exist for this block.

**Setting an object and unsetting keys**

By defining `const obj = { /* keys */ }` we define a value `obj` that is constant, but we can still treat the keys like any other variable, as is demonstrated by [the examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) in the MDN article. One could unset a key by setting it to null.

If it's [memory management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) that is the concern then both these techniques will help.

Comment: Re: _"const is scoped. By defining the constant in a block it will only exist for this block."_ Brilliantly simple, thank you. In a development (ie. as yet unfinished) script, I needed to avoid declaring a `const` several times. After reading this I realised the most straightforward solution would be to declare the `const` in an [**IIFE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

Answer (score 33):

The `delete` operator is actually for deleting an **object property**, not a variable. In fact, in strict mode, [`delete foo` is a syntax error](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-delete-operator-static-semantics-early-errors).

Usually you can "delete" a value/object by removing all references to it, e.g. assigning `null` to a variable.

However, since constants are not writable (by definition) there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 12):

As I wrote on my comment, delete can only be used on objects and arrays. So, what you can actually do is store all your constants in a constant object and free up memory by deleting it's properties, like this:

```
const myConstants = {};
myConstants.height = 100;

delete myConstants.height;
```

Answer (score 2):

Would this piece of code work or is it counterproductive?

```js
export default function freeObject(object) {
  const keys = Object.keys(object)
  for (const key of keys) {
    delete object[key]
  }
}
```

Comment: No need to downvote without providing feedback. Take +10 for taking the time ;)