# How to change the value of let node.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules

How can i remove the result value from code permanently  after user got that value? {Is it possible} ?

```
let word = ['idk', 'xd', ' i'];
        const random = Math.floor((Math.random() * word.length));
        const result = word[random];

  
message.author.send(`${message.author} here ${result}`)
         return message.channel.send (`${message.author} check your DM`);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unset a Javascript Constant in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291436/how-to-unset-a-javascript-constant-in-es6)

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. Please sort out *in the body of this question*: `remove [something] from code permanently` How shall this be interpreted: 1) active part: you (use a source code editor), a process (execution of your code)? 2) desired effect? 3) permanence: for the remaining part of a process? Forever?