# Overwrite anonymous const function in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants

I was trying to figure this out with a friend.

Let's say you have a function like this:

`const foo = function(i) { return function(j){ return 2 * j } };`

How would I override `foo` with a different method?

Let's say I want to reuse `foo` with a different anonymous function that does something like `function(j){ return 3 * j; };`

How would I do that?

EDIT: I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016272/delete-or-override-const-variables-in-javascript-harmony-ecmascript-6), but that's for variables. I'm asking specifically about anonymous methods.

EDIT 2: This is a proof of concept, so let's say that `foo` is a `const` and I can't turn it into a `let`

Comment: You can't reassign a `const` since by definition they are constant. You could assign an object containing the function (`const foo = {method: function () {} }; foo.method = newFunction`), but at that point might as well use `let` instead of `const`

Comment: It's a `const`ant - the whole point is to be readonly.

Comment: Loosely related to this question, but check out currying https://medium.com/@kbrainwave/currying-in-javascript-ce6da2d324fe . This technique allows you to compose functions and in this case, allow you to build multiple function where the parameter is multiplied by a different constant

Comment: *"I'm asking specifically about anonymous methods."* ... anonymous methods that are referred to by const variables.  The same answers apply. You can create a new function all you want, but you can't replace the reference with the new function.

Answer (score 0):

- [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) is used for **constants**, so it's **not for overriding**.
- If you want to override your variable, **use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) or `var`**

```js
const constantFunction = x => x + 1;
let variableFunction = x => x + 2;

try {
  variableFunction = x => x + 3;
  console.log('Re-assigning to a variable: DONE');
} catch(e) {
  console.log('Error while re-assigning to a variable');
}

try {
  constantFunction = x => x + 3;
  console.log('Re-assigning to a constant: DONE');
} catch(e) {
  console.log('Error while re-assigning to a constant');
}
```

Comment: Right, but let's say for argument's sake that so let's say that `foo` is a `const` and I can't turn it into a `let`

Comment: You can copy it into another variable that's declared with a `let`