# Spidermonkey: How do I delete the global object

Tags: javascript, c, spidermonkey

I can create a global objects with

```
JS_NewCompartmentAndGlobalObject
```

(SM 1.8.5) or a similar function

but how do I delete the global object. As far as I know the global object is rooted and thus no GC thing. At the end I can call JS_DestroyContext but to call JS_GC I must have a context. When is the global object garbage collected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JS_DestroyContext` call does garbage collection to reclaim memory used by the context's global. Presumably you should set your `JS::Rooted` to `JSVAL_NULL` before destroying the context so there are no stack roots of the global when the GC runs.

Answer (score 0):

Read this topic [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596782/how-to-unset-a-javascript-variable). You need to create you object using `var` if you want to remove it in future. Or if you don't want to use it just put to it `null`. if this object was created without `var` it will not be processed by your GC until you don't close the window.