# In Java Script Global Variable is not clear

Tags: javascript

I have declare global variable in java script, i try to clear with following code but it not clear.

As i defined global variable.

var usno;

then before set value i tried following code

```
delete window.usno;
usno = undefined;
usno=null;
```

but no success.

Please help on this

Thanks
Basit.

Comment: "No success" at what? What are you trying to do? What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

In short, you cannot delete variables defined with `var`. If you set the variable using `window.usno` then it can be. See [Understanding delete](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/) and the answers to [How to unset a JavaScript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596782/how-to-unset-a-javascript-variable) for more details.

Do you really need to delete the variable though? Instead of making a global variable, restrict the scope of your variable to a function so that it will be garbage collected after the scope of the function ends.

Comment: I don't know whether i want to delete or not. for what purpose im using is when user login the saved value in usno. suppose when i run the login screen when user "A" is login i save A value in usno and when user "B" login then i save B value in usno. but what problem is taking always "A" value

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution is the correct one.

```
delete window.usno;
```

That deletes the property `usno` from the global `window` object. But here is where the confusion lies, when we test it:

```
window.usno; // -> undefined
```

So, a deleted or non-existent property returns `undefined`. Thus, in effect, the following two statements achieve much the same thing:

```
delete window.usno;
window.usno = undefined;
```

They are not **exactly** the same thing. In the second case, the `usno` property still exists, as you will find if your iterated through all of the properties of `window`.

Short answer:

```
delete window.usno;
```

Comment: not working, as i told you i used three of my line of code but no success.