# Can I delete global variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to delete all global variables that begin with '**Nwxp**'.

Therefore I iterate over all global variables.

Check if the beginning is equal with my string and then delete them.

However, the delete keyword doesn't delete my variables. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
var strNwxp    = "Nwxp";

for (var variable in global){
    var toCheck = variable.substring(0, 4);
    if (strNwxp === toCheck) {
        delete variable;
    }
}
```

Comment: can u check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596782/how-to-unset-a-javascript-variable

Comment: You don't want to remove object `variable` itself, you actually want to remove a property from `global` which name is stored in `variable`. You need to call `delete global[variable]` to do this.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Please post this as an answers…

Comment: Thanks for you help Yeldar. Appreciate it!

Comment: You can't delete a variable declared using var.
[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596782/how-to-unset-a-javascript-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying to remove a property called `variable`.
Instead, as far as I understand, you actually want to remove a property from `global` which name is stored in `variable` as a string.

You need to call `delete global[variable]` to do this:

```
var strNwxp = "Nwxp";

for (var variable in global)
{
    var toCheck = variable.substring(0, 4);
    if (strNwxp === toCheck) {
        delete global[variable];
    }
}
```

It assumes that `Nwxp*` properties are assigned directly to `global` not with `var`.
[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52037832/3218692) describes it much better.

Demo snippet with `global` changed to `window` for browser environment:

```js
window.NwxpHello = "World!";    
window.NwxpKey = "value";
window.NotNwxpKey = "another value";
    
var strNwxp = "Nwxp";

for (var variable in window)
{
    var toCheck = variable.substring(0, 4);
    if (strNwxp === toCheck) {
        delete window[variable];
    }
}

console.log(window.NwxpHello); // undefined, starts with "Nwxp" - was removed
console.log(window.NwxpKey); // undefined, starts with "Nwxp" - was removed
console.log(window.NotNwxpKey); // another value
```

Comment: Are you sure this works in JavScript as it gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined`

Comment: this doesn't work because variables declared with `var` are non-configurable (see `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal - Presumably this is in an environment that defines `global` (such as Node.js). In browsers, that's roughly equivalent to `window`.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I used `global`, because this is what the OP has used. I guess, he\she is working in Node.JS or other environment.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree with you but as a community user, we cannot assume that unless it is tagged with `NodeJS` or OP says so

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal - Yes, we can. The OP used `global` in their code, so an answer using `global` is perfectly acceptable. It may be Node.js, or it may be that the OP does `var global = this;` at global scope, or `var global = window;` in a browser, etc. That doesn't matter; they clearly have `global` defined somehow.

Comment: also, if the variable truly is global you don't actually need to do `delete global[name]` you can just do `delete name`.

Answer (score 4):

As [Yeldar Kurmangaliyev points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52037839/157247), you're deleting the wrong thing. But even if you delete the right thing, global variables created with `var` cannot be deleted. `delete` results in `false` in that case (`true` if the variable was created in a way it can be deleted, such as `global.foo = 42`). So **if** the globals you're trying to get rid of were created that way, it won't work.

Separately, note that not all global variables are properties of the global object anymore, not as of ES2015. Specifically, `let`, `const`, and `class` at global scope create globals that are not properties of the global object. (If you're using Node.js, you probably aren't using those at global scope, however.)

To ensure you can remove the global variable, don't use `var`, use assignment to a property on `global`:

```
global.Nwxplaskdflk = 42;
```

That global can be deleted.

---

A couple of notes:

1. I'm assuming `global` is a reference to the global object in your code. E.g., you're using Node.js or a similar environment that creates it, or you have `var global = this;` at global scope in your own code.
2. In general, if you can avoid creating globals, avoid creating globals. :-) Instead, use properties on some other object. (If the variable referring to that object has to be global for some reason, so be it, but the global namespace is **very** crowded, it's best to avoid adding to it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use -
`delete.[variableName]` after its work is done.