# how to delete object file or array file in a javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have file upload response as an object i need to delete this object when its clicked but its not working

my javascript code is :

```
var file_id = this;
var class_name = file_id.id;
for(var s=0;s<this.files.length;s++){
    console.log(this.files);
    Certificates.push(this.files[s]);
    form.append("doc", this.files[s], this.files[s].name);
    $("."+class_name).append('<span id="check'+ab+'"onmouseover="myclsFunction(this)" >'+this.files[s].name+'</span>');
    $("."+class_name).append('<img style = "border:0px;width:20px;display:none;margin-left: 8px;" id="clsimg'+ab+'" class="clsicon" src = "./images/closeRes.png" />');
    $("."+class_name).append('<br/>');
    console.log(form);
    console.log(this.files[s]);
    ab++;
}
```

this.files[s] is the object file and i need to delete it, how to delete this object?

Comment: Not sure about your particular use case but usually `delete file[s]` deletes a given object. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: You can remove it from the `this.files` object by adding `delete this.files[s]`

Comment: As in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25919959/12540953 try delete this.files[s];

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set its value to `null`. Something looks like `this.files[s] = null` will do the job.

Hope it works!

Comment: I didn't write any specific delete handler i just added this in the above for loop

Comment: it doesn't make sense. you're trying to delete `this.files` right before the loop. that loop will do nothing

Comment: for(var s=0;s<this.files.length;s++){
   
      Certificates.push(this.files[s]);
      form.append("doc", this.files[s], this.files[s].name);
      $("."+class_name).append('<span id="check'+ab+'"onmouseover="myclsFunction(this)" >'+this.files[s].name+'</span>');
      $("."+class_name).append('<img style = "border:0px;width:20px;display:none;margin-left: 8px;" id="clsimg'+ab+'" class="clsicon" src = "./images/closeRes.png" />');
      $("."+class_name).append('<br/>');
      console.log(form);
      this.files[s] = null;
      console.log(this.files[s]);
      
     }

Comment: not before the loop i print it once and i deleted it and then i print , no change reflected