# Why I can not delete global varaible in JS?

Tags: javascript

Using Chrome I passed in console this name of global variable:

```
multiConfig
```

And get result:

```
multi: {type: "1", containerId: "mp", go: {…}}
__proto__: Object
```

I try to delete this variable by click:

```
if (window['multiConfig']) {
    delete window['multiConfig'];
}
```

And I get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot delete property 'multiConfig' of [object Window]
```

Why?

Comment: It is not `configurable`. How is it defined in the first place?

Comment: it is define in the top of all scripts as `var multiConfig = {}`

Comment: If to do this `console.log(window);` before  `if (window['multiConfig']) {}` i see this global object

Comment: What do you get when running `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window,'multiConfig)`?

Comment: Below in question there are answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables declared with `var` are added as properties on the global `window` object and cannot be deleted with the `delete` operator.

From [MDN - var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#description):

> In the global context, a variable declared using var is added as a
> non-configurable property of the global object. This means its
> property descriptor cannot be changed and it cannot be deleted using
> delete.

Reason for this is also explained:

> The property created on the global object for global variables, is set
> to be non-configurable because the identifier is to be treated as a
> variable, rather than a straightforward property of the global object.
> JavaScript has automatic memory management, and it would make no sense
> to be able to use the delete operator on a global variable.

Also note that trying to delete a property set on of global `window` object for variables declared with `var` fails silently in non-strict mode and throws a `TypeError` in strict-mode.

Also note that you can delete a property from the `window` object if is set explicitly.

```js
var a = 1;      // can't be deleted
window.b = 2;   // can be deleted

delete window.a;
delete window.b;

console.log(window.a);
console.log(window.b);
```

Comment: Thank you, what if I use this window.config = {key: 1, key2: 2}; and want to delete key2 to get this: {key: 1}?

Comment: You can do: `var config =  {key: 1, key2: 2}; delete config.key2;` or `delete window.config.key2;`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete a `window` variable, but you can unset it:

```js
window['multiConfig'] = undefined;
```

**Reason:**

The `window` object is not configurable.
You can refer to this - [How to unset a JavaScript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596782/how-to-unset-a-javascript-variable)

Comment: Could I delete element from global obnjet by key or only undefine too?

`var multiConfig = {key: {props}}` I need delete element by key

Comment: Yes, you can mark any key as `undefined` and it will unset it.

Comment: Okay, but then I get globval object with a lot of keys and their values are undefined. Could I delete and keys?

Comment: Using a lot of global variables will make your `window` heavy - which is not recommended. Try not to overload the `window` if possible and use some state management libraries (like Redux) for maintaining global states.

Comment: No, I mean I have only one global object , custom with some keys, could I delete all keys in this object?

Comment: This will give you a clearer picture - Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete