# Avoid "Identifier '*' has already been declared" error

Tags: javascript, variables, dom

I'm making a client side page builder which can let user load the script into the DOM and remove it back.

The problem is - although user remove the script element from the DOM, the variables are still available inside the DOM.

When user re-add the script again, it causes this error.

```
"Identifier '*' has already been declared"
```

How to clear old variables and avoid this error?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this post - How can I unset a JavaScript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25919959).

Comment: @lejlun Not quite. That post doesn't touch on `const`s, which are the issue here.

Comment: Do not use global variables!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the user's code in an [IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to avoid them from "polluting" the global namespace with `const`s of their own devising.

That is, if the user enters (your example)

```
const test = () =>{
  console.log('hello')
}
test();
```

then wrap it as

```
(() => {
  const test = () =>{
    console.log('hello')
  }
  test();
}())
```

and that `test` remains within the IIFE.

However, this will not help with e.g.

```
a = 9;
```

which would still implicitly assign `a` into the global (`window` namespace), whether or not IIFE'd.

Comment: This fixes the issue but a little work for me that I have to wrap all input scripts from users. Any better option for it?

Comment: Not that I can think of. But isn't wrapping your users' scripts just, you know, `script = '(() => {' + script + '}())'` before you plonk it into the DOM? Not that much work.